# Syntax error when using concat function

Tags: qgis, syntaxerror, concatenation

I created a field to display the whole route of several photos in a point layer in order to be able to visualize them on the map. I try to do so by using this expression:

```
concat('C:\Users\DIDAC\Documents\CONSULT\EIA OLIVERES CLARAMUNT\treball camp\fotos\IGN\',"file_name")
```

"file_name" being the name of every photo.

Here's the error message: "syntax error, unexpected Unknown_CHARACTER"

Comment: Are you using this expression in the Field Calculator, or typing it directly into the attribute table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslash characters need to be escaped in qgis expression strings. Replace each backslash in the path with a double backslash '\'.

Comment: So would the final expression look like `concat('C:\\Users\\DIDAC\\Documents\\...`?

Comment: Correct. The \ character is used to begin other "special" characters, like a `\n` = newline character. To get an actual \ literal you need to use `\\`. (This is the same rules as Python or SQL languages)